# String to Int in to method in a let RecipeModel

Tags: swift, string, int

Ciao everyone,
i am new to Swift and I have some trouble to convert some variable from **String to Int** into method call 'newRecipe'.
I have try this solution but I don't know how I can put the new value in the code. Someone please help me? Thank you so much!

```
// Method to create a recipe
func newRecipe(titleRecipe: String, recipeTime: String, peopleRecipe: String, preparationTime: String, cookingTime: String, bakingTempRecipe: String, imageRecipe: UIImage)
{
    let newRecipe = RecipeModel(titleRecipe: titleRecipe,
                                recipeTime: recipeTimeInt,
                                peopleRecipe: peopleRecipe,
                                preparationTime: preparationTime,
                                cookingTime: cookingTime,
                                bakingTempRecipe: bakingTempRecipe,
                                imageRecipe: imageRecipe)

    // Make the var from String into Int
    // To calculate the value of recipeTime from addition of preparationTime and cookingTime
    if var recipeTimeInt = Int(recipeTime)
    {
        let preparationTimeInt = Int(preparationTime)
        let cookingTimeInt = Int(cookingTime)
        recipeTimeInt = preparationTimeInt! + cookingTimeInt!
    }

    recipes.append(newRecipe)
    salva()

    // reload the collection of recipeController
        recipeController?.collectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write something like that.. the ?? is so that if it can't convert the argument into Int it will add 0 to your variable myInt..

```
let myInt:Int = Int("1234") ?? 0
```

Comment: Et voilà my solution at the problem:`var recipeTimeInt: Int
    {
        var sumRecipeTime: Int = Int(recipeTime)!
        sumRecipeTime = Int(preparationTime)! + Int(cookingTime)!
        return sumRecipeTime
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this by creating an extension of String:

```
extension String {
  var toInt: Int {
    return Int(self) ?? 0
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
let preparationTimeInt = preparationTime.toInt
```

Comment: I don't know how use this in my code... ;(

Comment: @Davide Add the extension to a separate file, After that, wherever you're writing `Int(preparationTime)` replace this by `preparationTime.toInt`

Comment: @Davide Check Apple Documentation abour [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Comment: Thx @peter! I have add your solution in my code. But the compiler warning me about the 'var recipeTimeInt' is neve used. And my newRecipe is a 'let'...

Comment: `if var recipeTimeInt = recipeTime.toInt
    {
        let preparationTimeInt = preparationTime.toInt
        let cookingTimeInt = cookingTime.toInt
        recipeTimeInt = preparationTimeInt + cookingTimeInt
    }` This is how your code will look like after applyind my solution

Comment: @Davide It's giving compiler warning because you never actually used `recipeTimeInt`  in an expression.

Comment: Thx @Peter, I have try your expressions just, but the compiler give me another error: 'Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'' in 'if var recipeTimeInt'... I'm search some solution in the web... ;(

Comment: @Davide you can check `recipeTime.toInt != 0` instead of using `If let` because you already unwrapped the Int

Comment: Nothing... I need try another way... Thx for your attention!

Comment: @Davide For Converting String into `Optional Int` you can do `var toInt: Int? {
    return Int(self)
  }`

Comment: Et voilà my solution at the problem:`var recipeTimeInt: Int
    {
        var sumRecipeTime: Int = Int(recipeTime)!
        sumRecipeTime = Int(preparationTime)! + Int(cookingTime)!
        return sumRecipeTime
    }`

Comment: @Davide Great! Happy Coding!!